# influence of NO_CMAKE_PACKAGE_REGISTRY on CMake find_package()

Tags: cmake

I have the following `CMakeLists.txt` :

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.6)

set(CMAKE_MODULE_PATH "${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake")

find_package(FOO QUIET NO_CMAKE_PACKAGE_REGISTRY)
if (FOO_FOUND)
  message("FOO is found")
else (FOO_FOUND)
  message("FOO not found")
endif (FOO_FOUND)

find_package(FOO QUIET)
if (FOO_FOUND)
  message("FOO (2) is found")
else (FOO_FOUND)
  message("FOO (2) not found")
endif (FOO_FOUND)
```

There is a file `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/FindFOO.cmake`. However, when I run `cmake` it detects package `FOO` in the second case only:

```
-- (...)  
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info                        
-- Detecting CXX compiler ABI info - done
FOO not found                                        
FOO (2) is found                                     
-- Configuring done                                            
-- Generating done                                  
-- Build files have been written to: /home/me/tmp/build
```

My understanding of the documentation is that `NO_CMAKE_PACKAGE_REGISTRY` forbids `find_package()` to look at `~/.cmake/package/FOO` but I have nothing here. I have the same behavior with cmake 2.8.9 and cmake 3.5.1.

Why `find_package()` does not find the file in the first case ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two modes of [find_package](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_package.html): the first one, simple, searches `FindFOO.cmake` **module**, the second one, more complex, searches `FOOConfig.cmake` **config** file.

By default, CMake tries both modes, so *module* mode successfully finds your file.

But option `NO_CMAKE_PACKAGE_REGISTRY` is applicable only for *config* mode, which cannot find your file in any case. Same effect will be caused by

```
find_package(FOO NO_MODULE)
```

Comment: If I copy `FindFOO.cmake` into `FOOConfig.cmake` at the same place it does not work either. But if I define `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` to point to my local directory `${CMAKE_SOURCE_DIR}/cmake/` then it works in both case indeed. Thanks!

Comment: Different modes of `find_package()` uses different algothms for search and different variables. Variable `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`, which you set originally, affects on **module** mode only, variable `CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH` affects on **config** mode only.